# selenium can't find the element for the second time

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

When using selenium to send n emails within a for loop, it works fabulously for the first time and for the second time it successfully clicks the button, writes the mail and the subject, but misses the 'to' section.

`def send_mail():
driver.get('https://outlook.live.com/mail/0/')

```
for i in range(10):
    new_mail_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='New mail']")))
    new_mail_button.click()
    
    to = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='UKx9j']//div[@aria-label='To']")))
    to.send_keys('mail@gmail.com')

    subject = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@aria-label='Add a subject']")))
    subject.send_keys('demo')

    mail = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "(//div[@class='elementToProof'])[1]")))
    mail.send_keys('This is a demo mail sent by a machine.')

    time.sleep(1)
    ActionChains(driver) \
        .key_down(Keys.CONTROL) \
        .key_down(Keys.ENTER) \
        .perform()

    time. Sleep(2)`
```

I tried to refresh the page both within the driver and manually f5'ing by the keyboard module, with results that are the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest not to send emails via frontend and use one of mail http client libs.

But in any case, your test fails, as far as each time you're sending new email, textbox selector is changing dynamically. So `(//div[@class='elementToProof'])[1]` is incorrect when you are trying to send 2nd mail.

```py
    subject.send_keys('demo')

    mail = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[id*=editorParent] [role=textbox]")))
    mail.send_keys('This is a demo mail sent by a machine.')

    driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[Aria-label=Send]').click()
    wait.until(EC.invisibility_of_element(mail))
    #end of loop
```

In your code I changed:

- Changed selector to universal `[id*=editorParent] [role=textbox]`
- Changed logic from sending via hotkey to sending via button
- Except implicit wait added condition that waits for mail text box would be not visible

Comment: I already solved the problem but thank you for your time. This was a 'warm-up' project as in to get myself familiar with the module, but if I may ask, what do you think is the best way of sending automated messages to friends at Facebook? In a closed ecosystem like facebook's i would assume the only way to avert anti-spam measures would be selenium.

Comment: @Eugène-René Best practice is to use Facebook Messenger API is Facebook provides such methods. Like an exception, maybe Selenium would also deal with this task, but Facebook can have Cloudflare bot detection / or similar things that can prevent you from accessing via automation tools. 
Even executing native js code in browser that does that can be more working solution than using Selenium.
Also, I guess, you Facebook account can be banned after sending lots of message within small time interval.